# HTTP Query Builder Output

Tags: javascript, builder, encoder

I have a block of code for the http query builder. However, it causes problems in case of internal include object + array + object.

Encoder:

```js
const encoder = {
  encode: function(params, prefix) {
    var items = [];
    for (var field in params) {
      var key = prefix ? prefix + "[" + field + "]" : field;
      var type = typeof params[field];
      switch (type) {
        case "object":
          if (params[field].constructor == Array) {
            if (params[field].length > 0) {
              params[field].forEach(function(val) {
                items.push(key + "[]=" + val);
              }, this);
            } else {
              g
              items.push(key + "=");
            }
          } else {
            items = items.concat(this.encode(params[field], key));
          }
          break;
        case "function":
          break;
        default:
          items.push(key + "=" + params[field]);
          break;
      }
    }
    return items.join("&");
  }
}

let data = {
  "data": {
    "sub": {
      "sub2": [2, 3, 4]
    }
  }
}

let data2 = {
  "data": {
    "sub": [{
      "sub2": [2, 3, 4]
    }]
  }
}

console.log(encoder.encode(data))

console.log(encoder.encode(data2))
```

I can't get the whole query built.

Output: `data[sub][]=[object Object]`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I need url-encoder as RFC 3986.

Comment: I need the output of the http_build_query php function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. I extracted the $ .param part in jquery and I think there is a block of code that can do the job for many people. Thanks to everyone who helped.

```js
var rbracket = /\[\]$/,
    class2type = {}

function toType( obj ) {
    if ( obj == null ) {
        return obj + "";
    }
    
    // Support: Android <=2.3 only (functionish RegExp)
    return typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function" ?
        class2type[ toString.call( obj ) ] || "object" :
        typeof obj;
}

function isFunction( obj ) {
    return typeof obj === "function" && typeof obj.nodeType !== "number";
}

function isArrayLike( obj ) {

    var length = !!obj && "length" in obj && obj.length,
        type = toType( obj );
        
    if ( isFunction( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return type === "array" || length === 0 ||
        typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;
}
function each( obj, callback ) {
    var length, i = 0;

    if ( isArrayLike( obj ) ) {
        length = obj.length;
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for ( i in obj ) {
            if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
}

function buildParams( prefix, obj, traditional, add ) {
    var name;
    if ( Array.isArray( obj ) ) {
        // var buildParams = this.buildParams
        // Serialize array item.
        each( obj, function( i, v ) {
            
            if ( traditional || rbracket.test( prefix ) ) {

                // Treat each array item as a scalar.
                add( prefix, v );

            } else {

                // Item is non-scalar (array or object), encode its numeric index.
                buildParams(
                    prefix + "[" + ( typeof v === "object" && v != null ? i : "" ) + "]",
                    v,
                    traditional,
                    add
                );
            }
        } );

    } else if ( !traditional && toType( obj ) === "object" ) {

        // Serialize object item.
        for ( name in obj ) {
            if (Object.keys(obj[ name ]).length === 0) obj[ name ] = ''
            buildParams( prefix + "[" + name + "]", obj[ name ], traditional, add );
        }

    } else {

        // Serialize scalar item.
        add( prefix, obj );
    }
}

function param(a, traditional) {
    var prefix,
    s = [],
    add = function( key, valueOrFunction ) {

        // If value is a function, invoke it and use its return value
        var value = typeof valueOrFunction === "function" && typeof valueOrFunction.nodeType !== "number" 
            ? valueOrFunction() 
            : valueOrFunction;

        s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" +
            encodeURIComponent( value == null ? "" : value );
    };

    if ( a == null ) {
        return "";
    }

    // If an array was passed in, assume that it is an array of form elements.
    if ( Array.isArray( a )  /*|| ( a.jquery && !jQuery.isPlainObject( a ) )*/ ) {

        // Serialize the form elements
        this.each( a, function() {
            add( this.name, this.value );
        } );

    } else {

        // If traditional, encode the "old" way (the way 1.3.2 or older
        // did it), otherwise encode params recursively.
        for ( prefix in a ) {
            buildParams( prefix, a[ prefix ], traditional, add );
        }
    }

    // Return the resulting serialization
    return s.join( "&" );
}

export default {
    encode(a, traditional) {
        return param( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)), traditional)
    }
}
```

Usage:

`import Encoder from '../utils/encoder'`

`Encoder.param(obj)`

Comment: I wrote something similar to this a while ago, which makes use of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams it extends it with a URLSearchParams.fromObject(obj, ignoreArrayIndex, maxDepth) method. It can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/anotherCoward/orf4sLwz/ - Using this, I didn't had to worry about escaping, because URLSearchParams does this on the toString() method anyway. The URLSearchParams object returned, allows easy modification later on.